# pixijs: create custom event in sprite and listen in another sprite

Tags: events, pixi.js

I have two custom Sprites (in my case on is Sprite, another is Container, but this doesn't matter). I need to emit event in one sprite and listen to it in another sprite (`MyDragableElement`). In Application I have many `MyDraableElements: PIXI.Sprite`.
The idea is that second sprite will be able to manipulate on `MyDragableElement`, but it should know which element is selected. I decided that events can help here, but how this should be written in Typescript?

```
export class MyDragableElement extends PIXI.Sprite {
    constructor(

     super();

        this
        .on('pointerdown', this.onDragStart)
        .on('pointerup', this.onDragEnd)
        .on('pointerupoutside', this.onDragEnd)
        .on('pointermove', this.onDragMove);
    }

    private onDragStart(event) {
        this.emit('selectedElementChanged', this);
    }
}
```

So as you see this is some sprite and on drag start, it should emit global event.

Here is another Sprite, and it should listen to this event.

```
export class Toolbar extends PIXI.Container {
    selectedGameObject: any;

    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.addListener("selectedElementChanged", 
                (e:any) =>  { 
                    // this.selectedGameObject = need to select this element
                    console.log(e); 
                });
        }
     }
  }
```

Above is my idea, but it worn't work. No experience in Emitting events.

Answer (score 3):

I just learned this topic and can be wrong, but...

if you have some sprite

```
let mySprite = new Sprite(someTexture);
```

... you can write somewhere in you code the next:

```
mySprite.emit('customEvent', {myData: 'somedata'});
```

And you also need to set event handler for this customEvent on your sprite:

```
mySprite.on('customEvent', onCustomEvent);

let onCustomEvent = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
};
```